# jqgrid: getCell always returns false

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm currently working on a project that involves taking the value from a specific column of a jqgrid.  I've been told you should use 'getCell' for this, but instead of giving me a value, it always returns false.  Can anyone help me solve this?  My code to render my JqGrid is below:

```
RenderGrid: function () {
            var $deft = $("#MyGrid");
            $("#MyGrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                editurl: "<%=Session("BaseUri")%>" + '/path/to/irrelevant/helper/page',
                colNames: ['Actions', 'ButtonId', 'DefectCode', 'Name', ],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 100, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'ButtonId', index: 'ButtonId', editable: false, width:50 },
                    { name: 'DefectCode', index: 'DefectCode', editable: true, width: 50 },
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: false, width: 200, editable: true }



                ],
                pager: '#pMyGrid',
                caption: "McGriddles",
                multiselect: false,
                loadonce: false,
                rowNum: 10,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                width: new Number(300),
                gridview: true,
                height: "100%",
                data: ButtonLibrary,

                ondblClickRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                        jQuery("#MyGrid").restoreRow(lastSel);
                        lastSel = id;
                    }
                    jQuery("#MyGrid").editRow(id, true);

                },
                gridComplete: function () {

                    var ids = jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        var cl = ids[i];
                        be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#MyGrid').editRow('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                        se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#MyGrid').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                        var ButtonId = $('#MyGrid').jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'ButtonId');


//------------->         console.log(ButtonId); //always returns false
                            GBDelete = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='X' onclick=\"DeleteRowData('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                        jQuery("#MyGrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + GBDelete });
                    }
                }

            });


        },


        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getCell return false in two cases: 
1. If the column name can't be found in colModel or
2. the row id can not be found

For this purpose it is a good idea to have a column or data from the response, which acts as id.

When using local data as in your case it is a good idea to have set key:true in colModel array in order to work this correct.

Also my recommendation is to have a column which will act as id (be a sure it have unique value) and this should be set as key:true in colModel

EDIT: If you have difficulties with this, please post some data in order to look what is happen.

Also specify which version of jqGrid is used